# Was Thomas being sarcastic in John 11:16?

Tags: john

John 11:

> 14 So then he told them plainly, “Lazarus is dead, 15and for your sake I am glad I was not there, so that you may believe. But let us go to him.”
>
> 16 Then Thomas (also known as Didymus) said to the rest of the disciples, “Let us also go, that we may **die** with him.”

Was Thomas serious?
Was he being sarcastic?

John 20:

> 27 Then he said to Thomas, “Put your finger here; see my hands. Reach out your hand and put it into my side. Stop doubting and believe.”

Thomas' faith seemed to be lacking. How was this consistent with his words in John 11:16?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we have to comprehend first that, when talking about jewish people, it's very much possible, since they love making humour as we see in the following (**Matthew 12:3**) in the time the disciples of Jesus were in the of Sabbath hungry in a field:

> 3 But he said unto them, Have ye not read what David did, when he was
> an hungred, and they that were with him; (KJV)

Another one is in **John 10:32**:

> 32 Jesus answered them, Many good works have I shewed you from my
> Father; for which of those works do ye stone me? (KJV)

A curious one occurs when the people of Israel say to Moses this (**Exodus 14:11**):

> They said to Moses, “Is it because there are no graves in Egypt that
> you have taken us away to die in the wilderness? What have you done to
> us in bringing us out of Egypt? (ESV)

So, the coming out of Egypt was something good, however they didn't undertood that way, they wanted to be there strangely.

Well, that's not all, when the sons of Joseph were talking about inheritance with Joshua, it happend the following:

> 14 And the children of Joseph spake unto Joshua, saying, Why hast thou
> given me but one lot and one portion to inherit, seeing I am a great
> people, forasmuch as the Lord hath blessed me hitherto? (Joshua 17:14 KJV)

And comes Joshua with this:

> 15 And Joshua answered them, If thou be a **great (numerous)** people, then get thee
> up to the wood country, and cut down for thyself there in the land of
> the Perizzites and of the giants, if mount Ephraim be too narrow for
> thee.

In **1 Kings 18:27** appears also an example of idolatry:

> 27 And it came to pass at noon, that Elijah mocked them, and said, Cry
> aloud: for he is a god; either he is talking, or he is pursuing, or he
> is in a journey, or peradventure he sleepeth, and must be awaked. (KJV)

As we can see, there is a clear sarcarm of Elijah against Baal, when people worshiped him. Then, we conclude that there are many instances of irony and also sarcasm in the Bible. The difference between *irony* and *sarcasm* is that the first refers to the happening of something different from expected while the second concerns a type of the first, i.e., sarcasm is a remark or irony. Something that it has to be clear is that were not kidding, we are serious when we talk about jewish humour, so even if it's humorous, it's also serious, for isn't it better to cry from laugh rather than from somberness? Or isn't better to die with friends rather than alone **(John 11:16)**? And the last explanation of the joke meaning is: wasn't you that said that believe when seeing, why not touching it? **(John 20:27)**